# abap loop multiple tables in sync

Tags: loops, abap

I have encountered some issues making mass upload programs using abap. I have gathered all data into one table from web to sap table but then, I have to move content of these tables into 3 different tables in order to use other functions for this. Problem is, if I loop through one table, the other ones are not looping through sync.

```
TABLES
T_HEADER STRUCTURE  ZCST5000
T_DETAIL STRUCTURE  ZCSS5001
T_TIME STRUCTURE  ZCSS5002

LOOP AT T_HEADER

PERFORM XTY TABLES T_DETAIL
            USING LS_HEADER_TMP

PERFORM ZCC TABLES T_TIME
            USING LS_HEADER_TMP
                                              
ENDLOOP
```

This is example code. So if I loop through T_HEADER, it only loops through T_HEADER and won't loop through T_DEAIL and T_TIME in sync. They all same same row counts since these structures are originally from 1 table. So when T_HEADER row 1 is running this program, row 1 of T_DETAIL, T_TIME should be picked up and T_HEADER moves to row 2, T_DETAIL, T_TIME row 2 should be picked up. How do I tackle this? :(

Comment: You are using deprecated syntax, so I guess you are looking for an old statement like `READ TABLE t_detail INDEX 1.` Look at the ABAP documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classic syntax `READ TABLE itab INDEX n INTO struct` or the new syntax `struct = itab[ n ]` to read a specific line of a table into a structure by line-number.

So when you have three tables, and you can **guarantee** that they all have the same number of rows which all correspond to the rows of the other table with the same row number, you can do it like this (modern syntax):

```
DO lines( t_header ) TIMES.
    DATA(header) = t_header[ sy-index ].
    DATA(detail) = t_detail[ sy-index ].
    DATA(time) = t_time[ sy-index ].

    "You now have the corresponding lines in the structure-variables header, details and time
ENDDO.
```

Or this (obsolete syntax using tables with header lines like in the question)

```
DATA num_lines TYPE i.

DESCRIBE TABLE t_header LINES num_lines.
DO num_lines TIMES.
    READ TABLE t_header INDEX sy-index.
    READ TABLE t_detail INDEX sy-index.
    READ TABLE t_time INDEX sy-index.

    "You now have the corresponding lines in the header-lines
ENDDO.
```

Note that these two snippets will behave slightly differently in the error-case when `t_detail` or `t_time` have fewer lines than `t_header`. The first snippet will throw an exception, which will abort the program unless caught. The second snippet will keep running with the header-line from the previous loop iteration.